# Login and register using Asp.net Identity C# MVC Need to add our own table too

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, identity, membership-provider

I am using ASP.NET Identity for login mechanism. In register Page I have to store some more details from another model also.

My Question is, 
can I add details in my own table with system provided membership table(s) in same time?

Please guide me for the above thank you..

Comment: Are you wanting to store additional properties against the user, like mobile number, address etc?

Comment: yes. Exactly but in different(my own table)..

Comment: Any particular reason it has to be in another table?

Comment: Yes .. I have three kind of registrations. All are having different input data for all three registration.

Comment: OK, so you have 3 different registration pages too? I would probably extend the Register model that comes with the MVC template and add in the extra properties you need to track. Then inside the Register method you can extract those properties into a model of their own.

Comment: you can store these information in the same table too, by adding new columns to it, but keep them nullable and Extend your Model with the new properties.

Comment: @DavidG Let me explain what i understood. In the default registration table add all fields that may appear in the three different tables and three different tables(my own) are also there.Then add values to register table and corresponding table in the controller? Is that what u meant?

Comment: Not really. There is a `RegisterViewModel` (which isn't mapped to a database table) that you could extend with all the properties you need. It's probably in `Models/AccountViewModels.cs`. Then in your `AccountController`, in the `Register` method, after the line that says `if (result.Succeeded)` you can add in your own code to put the extra data into the other 3 tables.

Comment: Great, I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `RegisterViewModel` (which isn't mapped to a database table) that you could extend with all the properties you need. It's located in `Models/AccountViewModels.cs`. Then in your `AccountController`, in the `Register` method, after the line that says `if (result.Succeeded)` you can add in your own code to put the extra data into the other 3 tables.

Comment: What if the Identity table has been extended to include a foreign key to another table? i.e. I have an 'Organisation' table where the newly created users is assigned the 'Id' of the Organisation. The 'Organisation' record will need to be created first in order to assign an Id to the new user. Where in the register method should I create the 'Organisation' record, but don't commit it until the new user is successfully created?

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit vague!
What do you mean by (my table)?
Is it included in the user identity database? 
If so, then you will have to enable data migration of your dbContext (assuming u r using EF)

Then extend the dbContext `DbSet<>` to include any table you need.

If this doesn't answer your question, please edit your question with more information

Check this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun